# What experiment disproved single fluid theory of electricity?

Tags: electricity, history

I just can't understand how history of electricity goes on. What experiment disproved Benjamin Franklin's [fluid theory of electricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_theory_of_electricity)?

Answer (score 1):

In 1897 J. J. Thompson's cathode ray experiments suggested that electrical charges are discrete.  Later, the size of the charge was measured in Millikan's famous "oil drop" experiment:  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment

Comment: This doesn't address single-fluid versus two-fluid. I doubt that the fluid theories were though of at the time as implying anything about the corpuscular or continuous nature of charge.

Comment: What else would it man

Comment: Posted before I finished composing.  What else are you implying is meant by the "fluid theory" other than a continuous nature (as opposed to discrete) of the charge carriers.  If one glosses over that detail, then electricity IS a fluid (all-be-it a charged one).

Comment: The title of the question says "single fluid."